# Must a view controller always have a delegate in iPhone apps?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

I'm learning how to develop my own iPhone apps but I'm having a tough time understanding certain concepts.

First, am i right to say that for every view, there must be a view controller for it? And for every view controller, must there be a delegate for it?

Also, what is the role of mainWindow.nib? Most of the tutorials that i've read don't seem to touch that nib at all. What always happens is the setting up of a NavigationController as the root controller, which pushes another ViewController onto the stack and this ViewController will have another nib associated with it.

So can i assume that i can safely ignore the main window nib?

Answer (score 2):

It's all about [MVC (Model View Controller)](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/05/understanding-model-view-controller.html), innit?

**The Model**, well that's up to you - what does your app do? Think of it as the backend, the engine of your app, free of the cruft of font size decisions and touch events.

**The View**, Apple pretty much wrote that for you. You use their Textfields and tables and imageViews. You assemble them together using Interface Builder into your GUI (packaged as a .nib). You rarely, if ever need to subclass the standard view elements (in a game you want a custom View to draw to, as all your drawing is probably custom). You can break different parts of your GUI into different .nib files if this helps you manage them. It's entirely up to you.

**The Controller**, so you have probably got some work todo to enable your GUI to represent your model. You need Some Controllers. How many? However many is manageable by you. If you had a view containing 2 subviews would they each need a view controller? Nah, probably not. How complicated is your code to hook up the view to the model?

Some GUI patterns are so common that Apple even wrote the Controller code for you. EG the controller for a UINavigationBar, *UINavigationController*. So, if your app has hierarchical views that you need to navigate around and you need to display a navigation bar you can use an instance of UINavigationController instead of writing your own class. Yay!

Surely tho, the UINavigationController code (or any other viewController) can't magically know how to integrate with our model, with our view, can it? NO, it can't. In general in Cocoa if there is some class of object that mostly works off the shelf *but also* has optionally configurable behavoir - allowing us to tailor it to our needs - it is done by **Delegation**. ie `Instead` of subclassing UINavigationController we tell the specific instance of it where to find (for want of a better term) it's custom behavoir.

Why? Let's say you have a navigationController, a tableView and a textfield. UINavigationController mostly take care of your navigation needs but you have to have a crazy QUACK sound play each time the user moves to a new view. UITableView is mostly exactly everything you need from a table, EXCEPT you really want the third row in the table on the front page be twice the height of the other rows. And the standard, off -the-shelf UITextField pretty much takes care of your textfield needs EXCEPT you need your textfield to only be editable when the user is facing North. One way to handle this would be to create 3 new classes, a custom UINavigationController, a custom tableView and a custom textfield, and to use these instead. With delegation we could use the classes as they are and have one object be the delegate of all 3 instances - much cleaner.

Delegation is mostly optional, the docs will tell you when, and it's down to you and whether you need that custom behavoir.